# create c#(WinFrom) control in win32 app use c++/clr

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have two projects, one is a win32 program and other is a c++/cli dynamic library.

in c++/cli dynamic library,it export this function:

```
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;

LIB_API void Create(HWND parent){
    auto c = gcnew TextBox();
    c->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, 0);
    c->Name = "textBox1";
    c->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 21);
    c->Parent = Control::FromHandle(IntPtr(parent));
}
```

when the win32 program call this function, will create a `TextBox` control.
but it's not work.

The debug log shows that the `TextBox` was created,but use spy++ can't find it.

Comment: Where do you add the TextBox to the Controlls of the parent Control?

Comment: @DanielW.   is a qt widgets app,  this is code: ::Create((HWND)ui.widget->winId());

Comment: Mixing QT with Winforms? That sounds really ugly. Use either (or rather: neither, actually...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.

```
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;

LIB_API void Create(HWND parent){
    auto c = gcnew TextBox();
    //c->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, 0);
    c->Name = "textBox1";
    //c->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 21);
    //c->Parent = Control::FromHandle(IntPtr(parent));
    ::SetParent((HWND)c->Handle.ToPointer(), parent);
    ::MoveWindow((HWND)c->Handle.ToPointer(), 0, 0, 200, 200, true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**